# How to link and unlink frameworks depending on Deployment in iOS

Tags: ios, deployment, frameworks, linker

i want to know how to link frameworks and unlink automatically depending on deployment target.

For example Digits and Twitter Core frameworks are for minimum deployment target iOS 8.0 so i want to link these frameworks when app is running on iOS 8 and higher and when running on iOS 7 i do not want to link.

i also checked setting the Framework options in Build Phases to Optional but its did not work.

How i can specify these frameworks in Bridging Header file so that depending on Deployment that will be linked and unlinked automatically.

Comment: add a new target to your project, then under build phases you can add the framework or not depending if the target is for 7 or 8

Comment: i want to link or unlink frameworks in the same target.If my app is running on ios 7 that i do not want to link some frameworks and if its running  > 7 then i want to link.

Comment: i dont think thats possible, its either compiled in or its not.. cant change that at run time, can only choose to not use the methods or not

Answer (score 0):

You have to create different build targets based on you requirement. While releasing the app to app store you have to release different application which is built with corresponding target. Yo can't unlink on runtime